# Making 'Details' view be remembered for ALL programs' OpenFile windows

Tags: windows-explorer, file-management

I would like that, in any Windows program that uses save/open file dialogue-windows (that is, most programs!), the default view is Details, rather than Thumbnails or other views some programs seem to default to.

Changing the default view in File Explorer itself is easy enough from its options, however this does not apply to other programs that use such openFile-type Windows. Googling this for a while, including on this site, returned no workaround that I could try.

Comment: There isn't one. Many programs use their own version of the File Open and File Save Dialogs together with program specific preferences.

Answer (score 0):

As [DavidPostill](https://superuser.com/users/337631/davidpostill) has indicated, there is no common 'save as' dialog. Different applications are written using different tools. An application written in C# using WinForms will behave differently and show different dialog boxes to a VB6 application, or a Java application. Then add to the mix UWP, WPF, Win32... there are plenty of alternatives which exhibit different behaviours. Each will write preferences to the registry or a configuration file in its own platform-specific way, or based on what the developer has written.

Comment: Most File Open and File Save dialogs certainly appear to have the same template, even the defaulting to a thumbnail view. Thus, despite the negative vote this question (comically) got, it was completely plausible to assume that, like the Windows File Explorer whence they originate, that default can be overriden. I am however prepared to accept that in fact it\s just the appearance that is the same, and there is in fact no way to set a default view for the icons in those dialogs.

Comment: Imitation is the sincerest form of flattery. Many other control libraries copy the pattern of their predecessors or distant cousins, as it's what works and people are familiar with it. Imagine a new Save As dialogue where the controls are rotated 90° and the dialogue box is portrait. There would be outrage! UX has style patterns for a reason, and the biggest reasons are usability and familiarity.

Comment: Yes, I understand that :) Still, that in 'serious' Windows applications like Matlab and Photoshop, there is no way to define a standard view for those kinds of dialogs, is rather strange, as by contrast, other properties of those dialogs *are* inherited from the baseline View settings one can set in Windows, such as light/dark theme.

Comment: Again, that depends on the controls they use. If .Net Framework controls have support for inheriting preferences from the OS then that's cool (and likely the case). Java apps on the other hand... not so much.

Comment: ok, got it - thank you!